# Ionic2 - setRoot on logout/login crashes navigation

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm having some trouble with navigation. I'm using the new split pane. When the user logs out I do a setRoot inside the app.component and set it to the login page. When the user has logged in an observable gets a login value also in app.component and a setRoot(TabsPage) is done. When I then try to navigate inside the ion-split-pane it throws an exception due to the queue inside NavControllerBase being null..

I've recreated the same error in this repository: https://github.com/oddcb/ionic-split-pane-example

Try to navigate the menu first without clicking the button in the Home view. Then click the button and try navigation again.

It crashes with:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null
    at NavControllerBase._queueTrns (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:45173:20)
    at NavControllerBase._setPages (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:45103:21)
    at NavControllerBase.setRoot (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:45077:21)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:84883:39)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1354:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1303:22)
    at Subscriber._next (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1256:26)
    at Subscriber.next (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1220:18)
    at Subject.next (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:7729:25)
    at SplitCommunication.setRootPage (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20749:26)
    at MenuLevel1.viewLevel2 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:84724:33)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_MenuLevel10.handleEvent_13 (/AppModule/MenuLevel1/component.ngfactory.js:201:34)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:134705:37)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:58120:53)
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10284)`

Any ideas?

Comment: does it work without the split pane?

Comment: I just tried setting another page as the first tab page. It also has navigation. Navigation after doing the setRoot in app.component then worked. But still failed in the split pane tab. Though the page I tried on now of course does not have its own ion-navs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had a rxjs subscription as a source of the failing navigation. When I did a setRoot on the parent stack that subscription was not unsubscribed. On navigation after the parent stack was replaced the old subscription would try to invoke the navigation and then fail since the old stack was gone.

Solved by doing unsubscribe in the ionViewWillUnload lifecycle hook.